# Clustering Method

Tags: cluster-analysis, social-networking, hierarchical-clustering

all. I'm totally new to Data Clustering and I was wondering if we want to perform **Social Network Analysis or Visualization**, what type of Clustering Technique is it based on?

There are like several categories of clustering methods such as Hierarchy-based, Density-based, Grid-based, etc. I'm not sure which one this Social Network Visualization falls into. **Is it Grid-based**? I did try googling but found none that answers :(

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Networks are *graphs*.

So you will need to use a graph clustering algorithm.